# Can an "apt upgrade" automatically install a dependent package that replaces an installed package?

Tags: apt, deb

Our team has gotten off into a dark corner of how apt updates work, and we could use some help finding our way out.

The context here is a set of deployments from a local repository. We have a package, call it `foo`, which is currently installed on all machines.  We also have a new package, `betterfoo`, which is annotated with `Replaces: foo`, `Conflicts: foo`, and `Provides: foo`.

This works as expected.  If someone manually installs `betterfoo`, `foo` is uninstalled first, and the files are all good.

Now, the problem is that we have a second package, `bar`, currently at version 2.0.  For the version 2.1 update, we'd like to add a dependency on `betterfoo`.

Unfortunately, when we add that dependency to version 2.1 and put it in the repository, `apt upgrade` does not install the updated package.  The error appears to be `bar: Depends: betterfoo but it is not going to be installed`.

If we manually do `apt install bar`, then it installs `betterfoo` (replacing `foo`) and all is well.  Similarly, if we first do `apt install betterfoo`, then `apt upgrade` will succeed.

**Is there any way to set things up so that `apt upgrade` will automatically replace `foo` with `betterfoo` on the machines where `bar` is already installed?**

Some additional notes, in case they're relevant:

- A constraint: We can't just automatically replace `foo` with `betterfoo` everywhere.
- We are set up so that `foo` is in a higher-priority repository than `betterfoo`.  If that's the cause of the problem, we can fix that.
- Likewise, `foo` is at version 3.0, and `betterfoo` is at version 1.0.  Do we need a version number on the `Provides:` entry on `betterfoo`, perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried `apt full-upgrade`/`apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @muru!  We'll give it a try.  This is deployed on about 100 user machines so we would much prefer a zero-touch solution that works when they run "apt upgrade" automatically, but it at least would be a simple manual solution if it comes to that.

Comment: `Provides: foo` seems to be the reason; the whole concept is illogical from a package-manager's perspective... you can either have the one or other the other, but not both.

Comment: @MartinZeitler: I'm not sure I follow. In this case, "betterfoo" provides the functionality of "foo", and this annotation is needed so that installing it won't break dependencies for things that have "Depends: foo".  This combination of annotations seems to be standard; e.g., https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#replacing-whole-packages-forcing-their-removal.

Comment: @BrooksMoses what you have there might work for meta packages - but likely you'd have to update the dependencies of the other package, depending on `foo`. See [7.5 Overwriting files and replacing packages](http://www.fifi.org/doc/debian-policy/policy.html/ch-relationships.html#s-replaces).

Comment: The general solution here is to prepare a newer version of `foo` which depends on `betterfoo`; is that doable for you?

Comment: @StephenKitt: See the caveat that "We can't just automatically replace `foo` with `betterfoo` everywhere."  We don't want `betterfoo` on all the machines that currently have `foo` but not `bar`.  (The `betterfoo` name is kind of a misnomer for sake of the example; it's really `worsefoo` but it has things `bar` needs.)

Comment: @MartinZeitler: Similar to my comment to @StephenKitt -- we don't want to replace `foo` with `betterfoo` in the general case.  We just want it replaced on the machines where `bar` is installed.  So I don't think section 7.5 quite applies, and we certainly want the other package to depend on `foo` only.

Comment: And there’s no way to make `bar` use a `worsefoo` which can be installed in parallel with `foo`, is there?

Comment: @StephenKitt It should be obvious, that when using provides & conflicts, there can only be one. Just see how other packages, which provide different versions, are being packaged.

Comment: @Martin it may not be obvious but [I do think I have some vague notions of what can be done in Debian packages](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=skitt%40debian.org). In this instance, since `bar` probably needs to be changed anyway, it may be possible to change `worsefoo` so that it doesn’t conflict with `foo`, and adjust `bar` accordingly.

Comment: @StephenKitt While we are talking about `foo` and `bar`, this is somewhat abstract... and this is certainly not specific to Debian, since all package managers share this concept.

Comment: @Martin so it’s not obvious that there can only be one ;-). Or rather, it is obvious that two packages set up in this way can’t be installed in parallel (and yes, in any package management system), but my question is whether the two packages *need* to conflict with each other. The OP is producing all the packages involved here, so we don’t have to be limited by the existing package metadata.